# Hbase put issue

Tags: shell, hbase, bigdata

I am new to Hbase.  I have a Hbase table, in which data is in the format of `long` as follows:

```
COLUMN                      CELL                                                                           
default:details            timestamp=1337007859494, value=\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xDFH                   
1 row(s) in 0.0360 seconds
```

I am trying to insert data into this table using a put command, but the value that I insert, is going in as a `string`, not as a `long`, as shown in the above format.

Can you please explain how I can do this using the put command from the Hbase shell.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you paste your put command here?

Comment: put 'es.xxx' ,'17032', 'ds:test_xv', Bytes.toBytes(99999)...In this,es:xxx is the table I am inserting the data into,17032 is the key and ds:test_xv is my column family key and the 99999 is the long value that i am trying to insert into,but its going as [B@15c2745 and not like the one in my example.

Comment: thats the thing. you are converting to Bytes.toBytes(9999) that means that it will convert to Bytearray. while fetching back its fetching as String B@15c2745

Comment: pls compose your question properly before posting in the forum. Its very difficult to guess the issue & answer with out seeing what you have done. (means what is your input and what output you are expecting...)

Comment: ok,thanks...But any idea how I can store the long value in the Hbase to get to the format that I am expecting in question(like \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xDFH) using the put command.

Comment: not very sure pls try Bytes.toStringBinary (long)

Comment: yeah,thats what i thought too,but how do I define the long variable in put command.Meaning,if I give Bytes.toStringBinary(12345) ...then it gives me an error as :NameError: no method 'toStringBinary' for arguments (org.jruby.RubyFixnum) on Java::OrgApacheHadoopHbaseUtil::Bytes

Answer (score 0):

Converting to `Bytes.toBytes(9999)` that means that it will convert to `Bytearray`. while fetching back its fetching as `String B@15c2745`

please see the documentation of [Bytes](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/Bytes.html)